# Ruby version trouble when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the following version of Ruby: ruby-1.9.3-p36. Although I get this error when I run rvm.

```
$ rvm list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p362'.

rvm rubies

    ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
 =* ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
    ruby-2.0.0-rc1 [ x86_64 ]
```

I just deployed to Heroku and I get application error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p550 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p550'
```

Why is Heroku trying to use 'p550'?

Comment: heroku suggests you add your ruby version to your `Gemfile` - have you done that?

Comment: Yes I have ruby '1.9.3' However I cannot specified the 'p550'

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has a limited set of available ruby versions and patchlevels which are listed on [the support pages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support).

Among those are MRI `ruby-1.9.3-p550` but not `p362`

Your first step should be to install `p550` locally:

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p550
```

You can get bundler to warn about patchlevel missmatches by adding `patchlevel` to your Gemfile ruby requirement.

```
ruby '1.9.3', :patchlevel => '550'
```

You can get RVM to automatically switch to the correct ruby version when you change into a project directory by adding a `.ruby-version` file:

```
$ echo ruby-1.9.3-p550 > .ruby-version
```